# find certain text in lines, then hide those lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am running a javascript that looks through each line. I'd like to be able to search each line and if the line contains certain text, then hide that line. So for example:

```
  <input id="search" type="button" value="Run" />
  <textarea id="main" style="height:150px;">
   300 300 300
   300 200 300
   100 100 150
  </textarea>
```

Javascript

```
$('#search').bind('click', function () {
    var lines = $("#main").val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if($([i].contains('300' || '200'){
            $(lines).css('display','none');
        }
    }

});
```

The code breaks the lines, so in this instance its 3 rows. But how do I tell it to find certain text from each row and to not display that row instead of just taking out the number. So from above the output would be:

```
    100 100 150
```

Comment: You can not hide text inside `textarea`, but can remove it!

Comment: yeah thats fine to remove it

Comment: or if i need to use a div instead of a textarea thats fine too

Comment: Also makes the `if` makes no sense ... don't wrap arbitrary strings in `$()` and `if($())` will always be truthy unless you pass in garbage that throws error. Also `lines` is an array ... can't use `css()` on an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the whole textarea value. Since textarea only contains text there is no inner html for each line that can be hidden or styled in any way...it's all or none

Following filters the split array then joins it back using line break as delimiter

```js
$('#search').on('click', function() {
  $("#main").val(function(_, oldVal) {   
    return oldVal.split('\n').filter(function(str) {
      return str.indexOf('200') === -1 && str.indexOf('300')=== -1
    }).join('\n');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="button" value="Run" />
<textarea id="main" style="height:150px;">
  300 300 300
  300 200 300 
  100 100 150
</textarea>
```

Comment: so in theory, if i wanted to do the opposite, and only show values of say 200 or 300, then I would change the -1 to +1?

Comment: yes... can put whatever logic you want inside the filter function and just return a boolean

Answer (score 1):

```
  <textarea id="main" style="height:150px;">
    300 300 300
    300 200 300
    100 100 150
  </textarea>




  <script>
  var text_not_allow = ["200", "300"];

  //here, extracting the text innerHTML as posted. usually text area are kept in 'value' attribute
  var text_area_array =document.getElementById('main').innerHTML.split('\n');
  var final_text = '';



  for (var i=0;i<text_area_array;i++)
  {

    var line=text_area_array[i];

    var line_allow=true;
    for (var j=0;j<text_remove;j++)
    {
        if (line.includes(text_remove[j]))
        {line_allow=false;}
      }
      if (line_allow){final_text+=line + '\n'};
   }
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=final_text;
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not nearly as elegant as Charlies, but fwiw:

```js
$('#search').on('click', function () {
    var lines = $("#main").val().split("\n");
    var i = lines.length
    while (i--) {
        if( lines[i].indexOf('300') >-1 || lines[i].indexOf('200') > -1){
            lines.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      str += lines[i] + "\n";
    }
    $('#main').val(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="button" value="Run" />
<textarea id="main" style="height:150px;">
  300 300 300
  300 200 300
  100 100 150
</textarea>
```